# execute/open execute a program in c#

Tags: c#

Hello so i created a kind of launcher application, but i have a but of a problem when i try to use the launch button it just doesn't do anything here's my code. What i need is  a way to select the Arma folder trough the program that you have enterd but when i use the code it doesn't work?

```
private void iniSetup()
    {
        //Directory Read
        tb_arma3dir.Text = ini.IniReadValue("Directory", "ARMA3");
        tb_addondir.Text = ini.IniReadValue("Directory", "ADDON");
    }

    private void arma2OACheck()
    {
        string arma3Path = tb_arma3dir.Text;

        if (arma3Path.EndsWith(@"\"))
        arma3Path = arma3Path.TrimEnd('\'');

        if(!File.Exists(arma3Path + "\\ArmA2OA.exe"))
        {
            a3dir_pic.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("./Resources/redX.png", UriKind.Relative));
            a2Good = false;
        }
        else
        {
            a3dir_pic.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("./Resources/greenCheck.png", UriKind.Relative));
            a2Good = true;
        }

    }


    private void addonDirCheck()
    {

        string addonPath = tb_addondir.Text;

        if (addonPath.EndsWith(@"\"))
            addonPath = addonPath.TrimEnd('\'');

        if (!Directory.Exists(addonPath))
        {
            addondir_pic.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("./Resources/redX.png", UriKind.Relative));
            addonGood = false;
        }
        else
        {
            addondir_pic.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("./Resources/greenCheck.png", UriKind.Relative));
            addonGood = true;
        }

    }
private void CompileLaunchParams()
    {
        string launchStr = "";


        //  Lauch parameters
        launchStr += @"-mod=@TCG" + @" -ip=31.186.251.207" + @" -port=2302" + " -nosplash" + "-world=empty" + "-nosplash";

        // Parse game path
        string filename = "iniSetup";

        // Start game process as administrator
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(filename); // what do i use to select the program so it can execute?
        info.UseShellExecute = true;
        info.Verb = "runas";
        info.Arguments = launchStr;
        Process.Start(info);
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(a2Good & addonGood ) // if the addon and arma is good it launches
        {
            CompileLaunchParams();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not all settings are configured, Please click the gear in the top right to define options!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you mean _when i use the code it doesn't work_? do you try debug your procedure?

Comment: First of all I'm sorry that i am not that clear. When i use the code it gives me a and compile it so (launching it) it gives a error with Process.Start(info); saying something about   ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(filename);

Comment: so whar error? can you provide error message?

Comment: It gives me this error : http://prntscr.com/5dsn94

Comment: what is `iniSetup` can you provide path to it?

Comment: Inisetup doesn't have a path  btw it should be in the code

Comment: you have: `string filename = "iniSetup";...;new ProcessStartInfo(filename)` it must path to real file

Comment: I got this  file selection how do i make so it gets the path file?      (string arma3Path = tb_arma3dir.Text;)

Comment: can you explain what you want do? anyway you can save path to file that you want rus as clas field

Comment: K so i have this  code that  gives me the option to select my arma path. it checks if it's good and then if its good it gives you the launch option. But how do i make it that i can use the location path for the executer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try save selected path to field in class like:

```
private string Arma3Path;

private void arma2OACheck()
{
    string path = tb_arma3dir.Text;

    if (path.EndsWith(@"\"))
    Arma3Path = path.TrimEnd('\'') + "\\ArmA2OA.exe";

    if(!File.Exists(Arma3Path))
    {
        a3dir_pic.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("./Resources/redX.png", UriKind.Relative));
        a2Good = false;
    }
    else
    {
        a3dir_pic.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("./Resources/greenCheck.png", UriKind.Relative));
        a2Good = true;
    }

}
```

and then use it like

```
private void CompileLaunchParams()
{
    string launchStr = "";


    //  Lauch parameters
    launchStr += @"-mod=@TCG" + @" -ip=31.186.251.207" + @" -port=2302" + " -nosplash" + "-world=empty" + "-nosplash";

    // Parse game path
    string filename = Arma3Path;

    // Start game process as administrator
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(filename); // what do i use to select the program so it can execute?
    info.UseShellExecute = true;
    info.Verb = "runas";
    info.Arguments = launchStr;
    Process.Start(info);
}
```